# Problem when creating matrix of values based on covariance matrix

Tags: r, covariance, matrix

I want to simulate a data set with similar covariance structure as my
observed data (which is a SNP by gene p-value matrix, dim ~600k*8368), and have calculated a covariance matrix (dimensions 8368*8368). So far I've tried two approaches to simulating data (all in R):

`rmvnorm` from the [mvtnorm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html), and by using the [Cholesky decomposition](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2010/09/cholesk-post-on-correlated-random-normal-generation/).

The problem is that the resulting covariance structure in my simulated data is very different from the original supplied covariance vector (but the code used is accurate as far as I can tell). Lets just look at some of the values:

```
    > cov8[1:4,1:4] # covariance of simulated data
        X1          X2         X3         X4
    X1 34515296.00    99956.69   369538.1  1749086.6
    X2    99956.69 34515296.00  2145289.9  -624961.1
    X3   369538.08  2145289.93 34515296.0  -163716.5
    X4  1749086.62  -624961.09  -163716.5 34515296.0
    > CEUcovar[1:4,1:4]
         [,1]         [,2]          [,3]         [,4]
    [1,] 0.1873402987  0.001837229  0.0009009272  0.010324521
    [2,] 0.0018372286  0.188665853  0.0124216535 -0.001755035
    [3,] 0.0009009272  0.012421654  0.1867835412 -0.000142395
    [4,] 0.0103245214 -0.001755035 -0.0001423950  0.192883488
```

So the distribution of the observed covariance is very narrow compared to the simulated data.

None of the eigenvalues of the observed covariance matrix are negative, and it appears to be a positive definite matrix. Here is what I did to create the simulated data (very straightforward):

```
    Chol <- chol(CEUcovar)
    Z <- matrix(rnorm(20351 * 8368), 8368)
    X <- t(Chol) %*% Z
    sample8 <- data.frame(as.matrix(t(X)))
    > dim(sample8)
    [1] 20351  8368
    cov8=cov(sample8,method='spearman')
```

(earlier I've also tried: `sample8 <- rmvnorm(1000,mean=rep(0,ncol(CEUcovar)), sigma=CEUcovar, method="eigen")` with as 'bad' results, much larger covariance values in the simulated data)

- Any ideas of WHY the simulated data have such a different covariance?
- Any experience with similar issues? Would be happy to supply the covariance matrix if anyone wants to give it a try.
- Is this an impossible task statistically?
- Any suggestions? Anything apparent that I left our or neglected?

I am aware that my supplied covariance matrix might differ from the true underlying covariance of the population. But my goal is to simulate a random data that captures (as much as possible) of the covariance that this observed data has, no matter how weird that covariance is.

*Clarification - my supplied covariance vector has values in [-10^-2, 0.3] while the resulting data has covariance of [-800000,5000000]. This is not what I am expecting. I wonder why this is the case, and how this might be explained.*

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Boo. Do you see this question as having statistical content, or *only* about how to get this done in R (ie a coding question)? If the latter, it really belongs on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), where it would also be more likely to get a satisfactory answer (although that doesn't make it a bad question). *Please don't cross-post* (SE strongly discourages this). If you think it should go to SO, just say so, & after a bit the moderators can migrate it for you.

Comment: Thanks gung. I'm believe I am using the correct code in R. So this might either be a statistical question, ie whether I am trying to do something that is simply not possible. Or the problem might be due to an issue that R has with this covariance matrix (and the question is posted on R-help https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/321409.html).

Comment: @Boo This might be related to the sample size and the speed of convergence of the estimation. You are trying to estimate p entries using $\approx 2.5p$ observations.

Comment: Thanks @Procrastinator. Do you mean because the original data and the simulated data are of diff sizes (1/30 of the size)? But I am simply using the covariance.

Comment: @Boo (It is possible that I am not properly understanding the problem). Yes, I tried on lower dimensions using for example a diagonal covariance matrix of size $4\times 4$ and estimating it using $10-30$ observations. The estimation is in many cases misleading. In your case you are estimating $8368\times 8367/2$ entries using $20351\times 8368$ observations.

Comment: @Procrastinator The original data is 600k*8368, from this I calculated a covar matrix (8368*8368). From the covar I want to simulate data with similar covariance. I did not expect to get covariance in the scale of several thousands, while the original data has covariance usually below 1.

Comment: @Boo I see, but I was also using that, given that the covariance matrix is symmetric, you are actually estimating only $8368\times 8367/2$ entries. You can simply input this in `rmvnorm(n,0,Sigma)` but note that if $n$ is not big enough, the estimated covariance matrix of the simulated sample might differ considerably from `Sigma`. For example `set.seed(1)` 
`cov(rmvnorm(10,rep(0,4),diag(4)))`. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @Procrastinator Yes, there is some variation around the expected value of 1 in the example you give. I expect values near 0 with small variation (supplied covariance), what I get is covariance [-800000,5000000].